# Подчеркивание текста

Tags: html, css

Как линию подчеркивания разместить на одной линии с текстом который не подчеркнут?

```html
<h1>ТЕКСТ<u>ТЕКСТ</u></h1>
```

Пример

[image: Пример]

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду сделать перечеркнутый горизонтально по середине текст?

Comment: @Anamnian Нет, нужно чтобы линия подчеркивания была чуть выше, на уровне текста который не подчеркнут.

Comment: Приложите картинку того, как должен выглядеть итоговый результат.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Приложил.

Comment: У вас на картинке явно используются разные шрифты и размеры для частей текста. В эту сторону и нужно вам двигаться.

Comment: @Anamnian Причём тут картинка? Это пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В трёх браузерах проверил - одинаково

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: left;
  color: orange;
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>snc <i>group</i></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 u {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

h1 u:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>ТЕКСТ<u>ТЕКСТ</u></h1>
```